# Escaping double qoutes inside DB::statement()

Tags: php, laravel, escaping

I exported data from one of my tables and I'm trying to make a Laravel migration out of. In order to make it work I'm using `DB::statement()` like this:

```
DB::statement("INSERT INTO `course` (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES (1, 'PHP programming "PHP for dummies"')");
```

How can I escape the double quotes in the **course.name** column, within `DB::statement()` quotes?

I tried escaping them with backslash - did not work.

Comment: You are missing double quote closing at the end.  Better follow Aladin's answer..

Comment: Thx, that was actually just a post typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addslashes('Some string with "quotes"')`.

Or also the ol' `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

A better way to do it is:

```
DB::statement("INSERT INTO `course` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES (?, ?)", [1, 'PHP programming "PHP for dummies"']);
```

Laravel will then take care of the rest.

Comment: Doing it the array-way would require creating the arrays manually for over 300 `INSERT`s. And unfortunately `addslashes()` doesn't help me within `DB::statement()`. I get **unexpected 'PHP'** error.

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to use a loop or some automation? A regex maybe? It's not really safe to directly inject code into a DB statement. I've added a new function you can use instead of addslashes

Comment: @lesssugar - Take the time to write parametrized queries. They do not only prevent from escaping issues, they also protect from SQL-injection, and preparing will make your queries faster if you do 300 consecutive inserts.